# Putting user created variables inside of an array

Tags: java

I want to put what the use puts in for x to be stored in the yourNumbers array, how would I do that? Edit: How would I clean up the println parts at the bottom, using loops.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
 public class array {
public class SS_Un8As1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] yourNumbers = new int[10];
    for (int counter=0; counter < yourNumbers.length; counter++){
        System.out.print("Enter your number: ");
        yourNumbers[counter] = scan.nextInt();
     }         
   System.out.println("Original numbers: " + yourNumbers[0] + "," + yourNumbers[1] + "," + yourNumbers[2] + "," + yourNumbers[3] + "," + yourNumbers[4] + "," + yourNumbers[5] + "," + yourNumbers[6] + "," + yourNumbers[7] + "," + yourNumbers[8] + "," + yourNumbers[9]);
   System.out.println("Original numbers multiplied by five: " + yourNumbers[0]*5 + "," + yourNumbers[1]*5 + "," + yourNumbers[2]*5 + "," + yourNumbers[3]*5 + "," + yourNumbers[4]*5 + "," + yourNumbers[5]*5 + "," + yourNumbers[6]*5 + "," + yourNumbers[7]*5 + "," + yourNumbers[8]*5 + "," + yourNumbers[9]*5);
   System.out.println("Original numbers minus the next number: " + (yourNumbers[0]-yourNumbers[1]) + "," + (yourNumbers[1]-yourNumbers[2]) + "," + (yourNumbers[2]-yourNumbers[3]) + "," + (yourNumbers[3]-yourNumbers[4]) + "," + (yourNumbers[4]-yourNumbers[5]) + "," + (yourNumbers[5]-yourNumbers[6]) + "," + (yourNumbers[6]-yourNumbers[7]) + "," + (yourNumbers[7]-yourNumbers[8]) + "," + (yourNumbers[8]-yourNumbers[9]) + "," + (yourNumbers[9]-yourNumbers[0]));
}
```

}

Comment: It should be < 9 and not < 10

Comment: @morpheus05 even better, he should store the length in a variable and use that

Comment: Find a good book on Java and read it.

Comment: the array has a .length field which would perform this task.

Comment: How would I clean up the bottom part of my code, my teachers says to use loops but I have no idea what she means by that.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
yourNumbers[counter] = x;
```

The above code is stating: store the value of `x` in the array `yourNumbers` in the index (position) `counter`. Because `counter` is the iteration variable of a `for` loop, each time the loop advances the counter the next value of `x` will be stored in the next available position in the array.

You *must* make sure that the length of the array is the same as the value of `counter`. In your code, do this:

```
int[] yourNumbers = new int[10];
```

Why? because `counter` goes from `0` to `9`, so the array must be of length `10`.

Comment: What does the [i] stand for?

Comment: he ment counter. Its the index variable of the array.

Comment: Even better, `for (int counter=0; counter < yourNumbers.length; counter++)`, to allow changing the length of the array in just one place.

Answer (score 2):

replace this

```
int x = scan.nextInt();
```

with

```
yourNumbers[counter] = scan.nextInt();
```

also, the condition should be `counter<9`, or better `counter<yourNumbers.length`

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass the input into the next element of the array, while inside the for loop:

```
yourNumbers[counter] = x;
```

I should also point out, however, that you should validate that your input is actually an integer before assigning x the value. If the value isn't an integer, your program will crash.